# IOException during HTTP request in BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, httpclient, boot

I have an Android application that has this statement that posts data to the server.

```
HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

When I start the application, this statement executes fine. I have made my application automatially start after booting. When it boots up, I am getting an IOEXCeption at this line with message my hostname. The host is running all the time as the same statement works fine when I start the application manually. This issue occurs only when the phone boots up.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

---

CommansWare,
   I have this new method in my onReceive call to check the network connection. With this my problem is resolved, meaning it posts the "in boot Completed" message and goes on executing the http request successfully but it looks like it does not exit the while look as the "not online" message showing up endlessly. How can it happen? Is this not the correct solution?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            while(!isOnline(context) )
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Not online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();   
            }

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "in boot completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }
        }

        protected boolean isOnline(Context context) {

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);    
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "returned true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                return true;        
            } 
            else 
            {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "returned false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

There may not be an active Internet connection at that point in time. After all, the device just powered on from being turned off. This is no different than any other OS.

You may need to do something to delay your HTTP operations until such time as an Internet connection is available. For example, your `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver could use `AlarmManager` and `set()` to arrange to get control again in a few minutes, by which time the device will hopefully be more stable. Of course, you will also want to use `ConnectivityManager` to determine whether there is an Internet connection at that time as well, and you may prefer to do some sophisticated receiver work to listen for a `ConnectivityManager` broadcast, to perhaps do your HTTP work a bit more quickly than you would get with the `AlarmManager` route.